# GUI issue with QLineEdit

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have GUI which contains many QLineEdit, I want it to be cleared as soon as user go to it again to modify his input, I'm using PyQt5 in designing and python 3 in scripting, what signal is needed here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Making%20non-clickable%20widgets%20clickable), code below simply adds click signal to Any widget, doesn't support click event (I used it in QlineEdit here)

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

def clickable(widget):

    class Filter(QObject):

        clicked = pyqtSignal()

        def eventFilter(self, obj, event):

            if obj == widget:
                if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                    if obj.rect().contains(event.pos()):
                        self.clicked.emit()
                        # The developer can opt for .emit(obj) to get the object within the slot.
                        return True

            return False

    filter = Filter(widget)
    widget.installEventFilter(filter)
    return filter.clicked
```

Comment: The answers that have a link as a main part are not adequate, because if the link breaks it would make your answer unusable, I recommend publishing the most important part of the content of the link. read [answer]

Comment: I'm glad this isn't a link, and you've already edited it, but you should elaborate on what exactly the problem is and how you solved it.

Comment: simply QLineEdit has no click signal , so above script added click event to it

Comment: answer is on wiki python : https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Making%20non-clickable%20widgets%20clickable?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=make+widget+accept+click&titlesearch=Titles

Answer (score 0):

A solution for this is to subclass a QLineEdit and override its focusInEvent method to emit a signal when the line edit gets focus.  Then connect that signal to a method that clears the line edit.

Here is an example:

```
class GUITest(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        self.line_edit = CustomLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_two = CustomLineEdit()

        self.line_edit.focus_in.connect(lambda: self.clear_line_edit(self.line_edit))
        self.line_edit_two.focus_in.connect(lambda: self.clear_line_edit(self.line_edit_two))

        self.layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.line_edit_two)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def clear_line_edit(self, line_edit):
        line_edit.clear()


class CustomLineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):

    focus_in = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def focusInEvent(self, QFocusEvent):
        self.focus_in.emit()
```

Comment: Actually I use Qt designer to generate Gui, not put my widgets directly to script

Comment: This approach will still work.  The only difference will be that you will need to tell Qt Designer to promote the widget to the custom class.  There are several tutorials online on how to do this.

Comment: please I need your help finding tutorial to custom class promotion by Qt designer

Comment: thank you , it make it clear , but also I faced some errors I can't understand it , could you help me please .....

Comment: This is off topic from the question you asked above.  Quickly judging by the error and without seeing any code, it looks like you supplied an argument to `self.__init__` when it does not take any arguments.  This is a problem for another question.  Before asking another question on that error though, I recommend you read [How to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)